# How do we provide file name in GZip in express(nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, express, zlib

The below code works fine and I am able to download file in Zip formant but it downloads the file as download_log.zip. How can I give a meaningful name of the file?

```
    exports.download = function(req,res){   
        var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
        var rstream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        rstream.pipe(gzip).pipe(res);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment; filename="your string here"`.